# Why does the drawing of Capt. Walker look just like Max?

Tags: mad-max

In *Beyond Thunderdome*, why does the [painting of Captain Walker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23SVHUPrUJ4) look *exactly* like Max? It seems like the lost children's mythology is crudely cobbled together from cultural artifacts, and not actually tied into any mystical prophecy (their idea of "Captain Walker" apparently came from a Viewmaster-type slide of an airline pilot who looks nothing like Max). Is it just a coincidence? Did they paint it after he arrived in order to convince him to help them?

[image]

Comment: Better picture here; http://i.stack.imgur.com/w5DEh.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They've obviously drawn the picture recently. Ignoring the lack of weathering on the portrait there are simply too many similarities for it to be any sort of coincidence:

- The one white-bandaged leg
- The circular golden belt buckle
- The salt+pepper white sideburns
- The **single** leather shoulderpad
- The black-leather cowboy boots
- The visible scar

and if that's not enough to convince you

- **The spider-monkey**

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the monkey!

Comment: Wow...didn't notice the spider monkey.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens - No-one ever notices the monkey... (evil laugh)